# how to return a function in a different class in python 3.3

Tags: python, function

I know this is a really bad description but how can i get this to work:

```
class Test1():
 def test_p1():
    print("This is part 1 of Test1")

def Test2():
 return test_p1()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve / what problem you want to solve, not what you think a solution should look like.

Comment: In reality, this is an example of When Not To Use A Class.  Since you're just learning about classes, you probably want to make an _instance_ and then call the _method_ using said instance.  Also, your class defs need an instance of self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are several options.

The most basic are:

### Create instance first

```
class Test1():
    def test_p1(self):
        print("This is part 1 of Test1")

def Test2():
    return Test1().test_p1()
```

However, you should use it when having new instance makes sense (depends on your API).

### Make it class method

```
class Test1():
    @classmethod
    def test_p1(cls):
        print("This is part 1 of Test1")

def Test2():
    return Test1.test_p1()
```

### Make it static method (discouraged)

```
class Test1():
    @staticmethod
    def test_p1():
        print("This is part 1 of Test1")

def Test2():
    return Test1.test_p1()
```

### Alternative: use inheritance

In some cases (maybe it is your case too, we do not know) it makes sense to actually utilize inheritance: create a class that will inherit from `Test1`. This way you can override parts of it and refer to parent methods. Example:

```
class Test1():
    def test_p1(self):
        print("This is part 1 of Test1")

class SomeOtherClass(Test1):
    def test2(self):
        return super(SomeOtherClass, self).test_p1()
```

and then use it like this:

```
my_instance = SomeOtherClass()
result = my_instance.test2()
```

But again, it really depends on your API / library.

### Alternative 2: module-level function

User @user2357112 correctly pointed out, that module-level function can be even better (simpler) idea:

```
def test_p1():
    print("This is part 1 of Test1")

def Test2():
    return test_p1()
```

### Side note: PEP8

To avoid confusion, as Python is really dynamic, you should give a "hint" to developers on what they are using, and in general follow coding style defined in PEP8:

- module names are `all_lower_case`,
- functions and methods are also `all_lower_case`,
- classes are `CamelCase` (same applies to factory-like functions returning class instances),
- constants are `ALL_UPPER_CASE`,
- object properies are `all_lower_case`,

(and many more - the above is only about non-confusing naming)

Comment: There's another option: make it module-level. People coming from languages like Java sometimes don't realize when module-level functions are appropriate.

Comment: @user2357112: Adjusted according to your proposal. It is hard to tell, which case is better for OP, as we probably see very simplified example, but for this example your solution is probably the best fit.

Answer (score 0):

Tadeck gave a detailed answer while I was typing mine, but here is my initial solution to what I believe you are trying to accomplish. I'm adding my input simply because I'm new to Python and I think a beginner's perspective may be beneficial for OP.

```
class Test1():
    def test_p1(self):
    print "This is part 1 of Test1"

def Test2():
    myTest = Test1()
    return myTest.test_p1()

Test2()
```

In your original code you attempt to call the `test_p1` method without ever instantiating the `Test1` class. So I did that first, `myTest = Test1()`, and then called the `test_p1()` method using my newly created `myTest` object.

Also, I added `self` to the argument list in the `test_p1` method. I don't exactly understand why but apparently the lack of `self` makes it an unbound method which causes some problems.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the class containing the functin. Call `Test1.test_p1()`.

(Works in python3, but not in 2.x as there is this fuzz about bound and unbound thingies.)

Maybe you would want to use capital letters for classes and minuscules for functions.

A more common case is the following:

You have a class that defines methods:

```
class Animal:
    def bark (self): print ('woof')
```

Then somewhere else you instantiate an object of this class and then invoke the method of the instance:

```
spike = Animal ()
spike.bark ()
```

Comment: This will lead to `test_p1()` being an unbound method, which means it doesn't get a `self` argument. So it's not called like method on the object but a static class method. In *most* cases that's exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Dear downvoters, in which aspect am I not answering OP's question?

Comment: While this technically works (in Python 3), it's almost certainly not what the OP should actually be doing. (Even in Python 3.)

Comment: Nevertheless this is what he asked for. I am not omniscient to know what OP would or should actually be doing.

Comment: Even in Python 3, this should be an instance method, module-level function, class method, or static method, in rough order of probable appropriateness.